# How can I hide response code 200 with Swashbuckle.AspNetCore?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core, swashbuckle

Ciao,

I'm working on a asp.net web api core (target framework .NET Core 2.1). I'm documenting my API using Swagger specifications. I chose to use Swashbuckle.AspNetCore library.

I have one simple create action like the following:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// My summary
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>My remarks</remarks>
    /// <param name="value">value</param>
    /// <response code="201">Created</response>
    /// <response code="400">Data not valid</response>
    /// <response code="500">Internal Server Error</response>
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody, BindRequired] EntityDto value)
    {
       ...
    }
```

The problem is that my generated *swagger.json* automatically created a "200 response". But because my action only creates entities it only returns 201 response. This is the following json fragment:

```
{
  ...
  "responses": {
    "200": {
      "description": "Success"
    },
    "201": {
      "description": "Created"
    },
    "400": {
      "description": "Data not valid"
    },
    "500": {
      "description": "Internal Server Error"
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Surfing on internet I've found *SwaggerResponseRemoveDefaults* attribute but seems that it is only supported in Full Framework projects.

How can I remove 200 response?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order not to include default response code into swagger, you can declare possible return codes

```
    /// <summary>
    /// My summary
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>My remarks</remarks>
    /// <param name="value">value</param>
    /// <returns>A newly created TodoItem</returns>
    /// <response code="201">Created</response>
    /// <response code="400">Data not valid</response>
    /// <response code="500">Internal Server Error</response>
    [HttpPost]
    [ProducesResponseType(201)]
    [ProducesResponseType(400)]
    [ProducesResponseType(500)]
    public void Post([FromBody] string value)
    {
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me.  I always get a default set of response codes regardless of the ProducesResponseType attributes that I use on the endpoint

Comment: @MylesJ. you need to add the 
 [ProducesResponseType(201)]
    [ProducesResponseType(400)]
    [ProducesResponseType(500)] in the controller method, have you tried this?

Comment: Note that this suggestion only works if the Type is left unspecified or a a specific type is defined in the attribute. If you explicitly indicate that the Type is null, the result has the default response code.